# How do I use one-hot encoding with cross-entropy loss?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I have tried using one-hot encoding for a multiclass classification of about 120 classes using a dog breed dataset. Also using resnet18. But the following error is shown when I run the code. Please help me solve the issue.

The code of my model is shown below:

```py
model = torchvision.models.resnet18()
op = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.001)
crit = nn.NLLLoss()
model.fc = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(512,120),
    nn.Dropout(inplace=True),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.LogSoftmax())

for i,(x,y) in enumerate(train_dl):
    # prepare one-hot vector
    y_oh=torch.zeors(y.shape[0],120)
    y_oh.scatter_(1, y.unsqueeze(1), 1)

    # do the prediction
    y_hat=model(x)
    y_=torch.max(y_hat)

    loss=crit(y,y_)
    op.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    op.step()
```

The error:

```
RuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-190-46a21ead759a> in <module>
       6 
       7     y_hat=model(x)
 ----> 8     loss=crit(y_oh,y_hat)
       9     op.zero_grad()
      10     loss.backward()

***RuntimeError: 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported***
```

Comment: Check this- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57327968/6075699

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`NLLLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#nllloss) you are using expects indices of the ground-truth target classes. Btw. you do not have to convert your targets into one-hot vectors and use directly the `y` tensor.

Note also that `NLLLoss` expect the distribution output distribution in the logarithmic domains, i.e., use `nn.LogSoftmax` instead of `nn.Softmax`.