# Get the right tensor size

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, tensor

I want to have the right tensor size, because I get the following error in line of `loss = criterion(out,target)`:

*Expected input batch_size (4200) to match target batch_size (64).*

How can I solve the challenge?

My output tensor has the size ([4200, 2]) and my target tensor ([64,2]).
The usecase is an image classification. There are two classes. My batch size is 64 and the images has a size of 180 x 115px in grayscale.
Please don't confiuse: There are some 'break' to test the code in the early state of development.
I load four batches, so 256 images.

With this method i will load my images:

```python
def dataPrep(list_of_data, data_path, category, quantity):
    global train_data
    target_list = []
    train_data_list = []
    
    transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
        ])
    
    len_data = len(train_data)
    print('Len_data: ', len_data)
    for item in list_of_data:
        f = random.choice(list_of_data)
        list_of_data.remove(f)
        print(data_path + f)
        try:
            img = Image.open(data_path +f)
        except:
            continue
        img_crop = img.crop((310,60,425,240))
        img_tensor = transform(img_crop)
        print(img_tensor.size())
        train_data_list.append(img_tensor)
        isPseudo = 0
        isTrue = 1
        if category == True:
            target = [isPseudo,isTrue]
        else:
            isPseudo =1
            isTrue = 0        
            target = [isPseudo, isTrue]
        
        target_list.append(target)
        if len(train_data_list) >=64:
            train_data.append((torch.stack(train_data_list), target_list))
            train_data_list = []
            target_list = []
            
        if (len_data*64 + quantity) <= len(train_data)*64:
            break
    print(len(train_data) *64)    
    return list_of_data
```

After I loaded the images, I create my model and optimizer.

```python
model = net.Netz()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr= 0.1, momentum = 0.8)
```

My class 'Netz' looks like this:

```python
class Netz(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Netz, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1,10, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10,20, kernel_size = 5)
        self.conv_dropout = nn.Dropout2d() 
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(320,60)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(60,2)
    
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.conv_dropout(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x,2)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = x.view(-1,320)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, -1)
```

At the end I will train my CNN:

```python
def trainM(epoch):
    model.train()
    batch_id = 0
    for batch_id, (data, target) in enumerate(net.train_data):
        #data = data.cuda()
        #target = target.cuda()
        target = torch.Tensor(target[64*batch_id:64*(batch_id+1)])
        data = Variable(data)
        target = Variable(target)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        out = model(data)
        criterion = F.nll_loss
        print('Size of out:', out.size())
        print('Size of target:', target.size())
        loss = criterion(out,target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        print('Tain Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(epoch,batch_id*len(data), len(net.train_data.dataset), 100*batch_id/len(net.train_data), loss.item()))
        batch_id += 1
        break

for item in range(0,10):
    trainM(item)
    break
```

Comment: The main problem is at Netz `x = x.view(-1,320)` you have 64 batches 20 channels 42 x 25 width and height if you reshape it to -1, 320 would get 4200 by 320.

Comment: Okay, I can't explain it for myself. What is the solution or the right parameters for the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is at Netz `x = x.view(-1,320)` you have 64 batches 20 channels 42 x 25 width and height if you reshape it to -1, 320 would get 4200 by 320.

I can suggest 3 possible options to preserve the batchsize;

1. (what is generally done) pad the input to become square, update convolution part so that its output before FC layers have high number of channels and small number of height and width. for instance obtain `x.shape = (batchsize, 128,2,2)` then make the `fc1 = Linear(512, 60)` and before that do `x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)`. (here before applying `fc1` you may do a 1x1 convolution).
2. make the number of channels at the end of convolutions 1 i.e. get something like `x.shape = (batchsize,1,42,25)` then adopt `fc1` accordingly.
3. do`x=reshape(*x.shape[:2], -1)` in other words preserve both chanel and batchsize. Add another FC layer `fc_e = Linear(20,1)` to to compress your channels.

```py
class Netz(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Netz, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1,10, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10,20, kernel_size = 5)
        self.conv_dropout = nn.Dropout2d() 
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1050,60)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(60,2)
        self.fce = nn.Linear(20,1)
    
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.conv_dropout(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x,2)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = x.reshape(x.shape[0],x.shape[1], -1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.fce(x.permute(0,2,1)).squeeze(-1)
        return F.log_softmax(x, -1)
```

keep in mind that you have a trade off between the amount of information you want to be represented (should be high) and the number of inputs of Linear layer (not that high). At  the end its a matter of how you chose to tackle the issue. The third one is the closest to your solution but I recommend figuring out a model complying with the first approach

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Later, I want to understand the your answer. For the moment I copy the code and run the code. Thereby,, I get the following error at line of ```loss = criterion(out, target) ```:
_0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported_
The size of _out_ and _target_ are the same now. The size is _torch.Size([64, 2])_ . 
How can I fix the error?

Comment: your target is 2d and you have two classes you need to convert the one hot encoded targets to just integers and make your target 1d. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57325844/pytorch-multi-target-not-supported-error-message) modify `dataPrep` to return the id of target rather than its one hot encoding.

Comment: Yes it works, know I have a loss value of _nan_ in the second training epoche:
`Train Epoch: 2 [960/2048 (47%)] Loss: 0.000000
Train Epoch: 2 [1024/2048 (50%)]        Loss: 16495875072.000000
Train Epoch: 2 [1088/2048 (53%)]        Loss: 942391791976448.000000
Train Epoch: 2 [1152/2048 (56%)]        Loss: nan
Train Epoch: 2 [1216/2048 (59%)]        Loss: nan`

Comment: I was thinking of how such a loss might be possible... it might be possible when you assign a number very close to 1 for classes that are 0 and 0 to classes that are 1. then -log(p_estimate) would become inf or very large. can you check your outputs and see if all of then are zero or not.

Comment: if all are zero then you would get a large loss for classes that are 1. or vise versa.

Comment: They are not all zero. Here is another cutout of epoche 2:
```Train Epoch: 2 [0/2048 (0%)]    Loss: 193856.984375
Train Epoch: 2 [64/2048 (3%)]   Loss: 0.000000
Train Epoch: 2 [128/2048 (6%)]  Loss: 20247.367188
Train Epoch: 2 [192/2048 (9%)]  Loss: 711.686340
Train Epoch: 2 [256/2048 (12%)] Loss: 1116.427979
Train Epoch: 2 [320/2048 (16%)] Loss: 1467.049561
Train Epoch: 2 [384/2048 (19%)] Loss: 0.000000```

Answer (score -1):

From what I can see, you need a line to split the data as you did with the target in the train loop like:

```
target = torch.Tensor(target[64*batch_id:64*(batch_id+1)])
data   = torch.Tensor(data[64*batch_id:64*(batch_id+1)])
```

Comment: That's has now effect. The tensors has the same size. What I did? I append ```data   = torch.Tensor(data[64*batch_id:64*(batch_id+1)])``` to my _trainM_ method and check the size of target and data. Before the line ```out = model(data)``` _data_ has the size _torch.Size([64, 1, 180, 115])_ and _target_ has the size _torch.Size([64, 2])_ .
After my model my _out_ variable still has the size of _torch.Size([4200, 2])_  :((